# Oracle : table always "exist" after drop table

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle and I have a strange thing.

I dropped a table using :

`drop table t_my_table`, and committed.

But when I launch `select * from t_my_table`, it shows the data, as if the table is not dropped.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting, it stills shows the data when I select.

And when I once again try with :

`drop table t_my_table`, it tells me that this table does not exist.

But if I run `select` again, the data is always there.

How is this possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: First thing I would check is all_objects for that object name

Comment: Can you please edit the question and share the commands that you just described in the question?

Comment: Maybe you have a view with the same name?

Comment: It's probably public synonym.

Comment: @Adder A view and a table cannot have the same name.

Comment: (Not related to your problem, but - `drop` is a DDL, you don't have to `commit` after that).

Comment: While I don't doubt what you describe, when dealing with issues like this it is _far_ better to put together a precise and concise demo,  execute it in sqlplus, then copy and paste the entire session to your post.  That way everyone can be assured of exactly what you are doing and seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this case?

```
create view t_my_table as
select 'I''m here' as txt  from dual;

drop table t_my_table;

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But

```
select * from t_my_table;

TXT     
--------
I'm here
```

solution of the most probably cause

```
select OBJECT_TYPE from user_objects where object_name = 'T_MY_TABLE';

OBJECT_TYPE        
-------------------
VIEW
```

You defined a view (or other object type other than TABLE), that can't be dropped with `DROP TABLE`, but can be *selected*.

Simple check in `USER_OBJECTS` the `OBJECT_TYPE`. You may alternatively see also `SYNONYM` as proposed in other answer.

Note that it is **not a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`**  as if you try to drop a Materialized View with `DROP TABLE` a different error message is raised:

```
ORA-12083: must use DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW to drop T_MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

What does this return?

```
select * from all_synonyms
where synonym_name = 'T_MY_TABLE';
```

I suspect there is a synonym T_MY_TABLE that points to a table in a different schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table t_my_table purge;
```

Specify PURGE if you want to drop the table and release the space associated with it in a single step. If you specify PURGE, then the database does not place the table and its dependent objects into the recycle bin.
...
Using this clause is equivalent to first dropping the table and then purging it from the recycle bin. This clause lets you save one step in the process. It also provides enhanced security if you want to prevent sensitive material from appearing in the recycle bin.

Comment: Even if you don't specify `purge` the table won't be accessible under the old name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something different is happening. 
Normal case would be:

```
SQL>      create table t1 as select 1 a from dual;

Table T1 created.

SQL>      drop table t1;

Table T1 dropped.

SQL>      select * from t1;

Error starting at line : 22 in command -
     select * from t1
Error at Command Line : 22 Column : 20
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

1. So what was the message after the drop table?
2. Is `t_my_table` really a table?

Try `select * from all_objects where lower(object_name) = 't_my_table'`