# Trouble creating SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I learning how to use Oracle SQL and running into an error when I try to create a table. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Topic                                                        
(
     Topic_ID   NUMBER      NOT NULL,
     Topic_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     Topic_Desc VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT Topic_PK PRIMARY KEY (Topic_ID)
);
```

The error is

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

I have reviewed my other tables several times and do not see any repeating names.

Comment: please check for view and synonym names. Also query `select * from user_objects where object_name = 'TOPIC'`

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528237/4808122)